# parse anonymous class does not implement abstract method

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-studio

I am trying to retrieve objects from Parse cloud storage in a button click event in my Main Activity, this is the simple code I copied from the parse.com site examples:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("WtestObj2");
    query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {

        public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                //
            } else {
                //
            }
        }
    });
```

when I build I get the following error, it seems like my "new CountCallback" is creating an anonymous calss which does not implement an abstract method, but I copied the code 100% from parse.com online docs [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html), what else could be wrong in my Android Studio project?

> 'anonymous com.mobilevision.wtrend.MainActivity$4' is not abstract and
>   does not override abstract method done(int,ParseException) in
>   CountCallback

Comment: Do you have the correct `ParseException` imported? That is, `com.parse.ParseException`, not `java.text.ParseException`.

Comment: @MikeM. that was it thanks! if you make it as an answer will vote it and make it a solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would seem that you have (or possibly your IDE has) imported the wrong `ParseException` class. It should be `com.parse.ParseException`.

Comment: It doesn't need to import any exception.  It is all done by Gradle!